# Save a pdf to parse server with a HTTP request with angular JS

Tags: angularjs, parse-server

I'm trying to attach a file with one of these formats: pdf, docx, xlsx, pptx to an object in parse server. The complication here is that I'm trying to achieve this using the parse rest API with an HTTP request using angularjs (not the parse server JavaScript API).

I've written some code that can be used to associate a text file with an object, however, I'm struggling to see how this would translate to uploading a file with one of the formats mentioned above.

```
var data = {"Hello, World!"};

var config = {
  "X-Parse-Application-Id": ${APPLICATION_ID}
  "X-Parse-REST-API-Key": ${REST_API_KEY}
  "Content-Type": "text/plain"
}

$http.post("https://parseapi.back4app.com/classes/myClass/", data, config);
```

The content-type header in this example would seem to indicate that I would need the MIME type for the given file that I want to upload. I am aware that for pdf if it `application/pdf` but I'm guessing I would need to dynamically generate this for a given file?

I would be grateful if someone could point me in the right direction as the [documentation](http://docs.parseplatform.org/rest/guide/#files) for my specific use case seems to be non-existent.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the 'files' REST API for storage of files on your parse server. There is more info at http://docs.parseplatform.org/rest/guide/#files

Comment: Thanks - I've already thoroughly read that documentation - my issue is specifically related to the **type** of files I want to upload. It only provides an explanation for uploading txt and jpg files. I want to upload pdf, docx, xlsx and pptx.